# Restoring MySQL database from physical files

Tags: mysql, backup, restore

Is it possible to restore a MySQL database from the physical database files. I have a directory that has the following file types:

client.frm
client.MYD
client.MYI

but for about 20 more tables.

I usually use mysqldump or a similar tool to get everything in 1 SQL file so what is the way to deal with these types of files?

Comment: I have the same issue: multiple files with extensions FRM, MYD and MYI.
I also have files ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 and ibdata1.
I cannot access a running server or create a dump.
I tried running a new MySQL server and use the files, but I didn't suceed... Does anyone have a clear how-to?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

A MySQL MyISAM table is the combination of three files:

- The FRM file is the table definition.
- The MYD file is where the actual data is stored.
- The MYI file is where the indexes created on the table are stored.

You should be able to restore by copying them in your database folder (In linux, the default location is `/var/lib/mysql/`)

You should do it while the server is not running.

Comment: this is true only for MyISAM tables. InnoDB stores its tables and indexes in a single tablespace *, which by default consist of the 3 files ibdata1, ib_logfile0, and ib_logfile1. for restoring a database, you would also need those files.

* per-table tablespaces are possible, but not default

Comment: He says he have .frm .myi and .myd files. I then assumed it was MyISAM tables.

Comment: @ax is it possible to get data from InnoDB without the ibdata? I have a months old backup, and only the current ib_logfile* and .frm files.

Comment: @ax you added info to make this question more general, I did copied the frm etc files, but I didn't copy the ibdata1 etc, which made me search this question - so I am really thankful to you for mentioning that

Comment: Valuable answer, but I had to go one step further for things to work fine: since I had to log in as root to restore the files, the `mysql` user running the `mysqld` process couldn't access them. Doing a `chmod -R mysql:mysql .` on the mysql data directory is quick and easy, but figuring out, before that, why all my resoterd DBs seemed to have no tables took a bit longer.

Comment: I have the same problem as the previous comment. Mysql shows the tables of the pasted database when I run `show tables;` but it returns `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mydb.myrnd_categories' doesn't exist` error when I run `select` query.

Comment: herenvardo I think you meant chown not chmod

Comment: You can do it while the server is running (at least if those tables do not already exist).  The new tables will appear almost immediately (again, noting that it only works with MyISAM, and you have to have the correct permissions on the files)

Comment: To recap some of the important notes, you may have to `chown` the copied files like so: `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`

Comment: as described in the answer posted by @Filip Ekberg, you should restore permissions.

In my case after I restored databases from mysql v5.5 to a mysql v5.7 instance, running `mysqlcheck --all-databases -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -r` seemed to convert fields from the old tables to new v 5.7 format, plus displaying several warnings due to various inconsistencies.

Comment: "You should do it while the server is not running" - what are the possible dangers if the server *is* running?

Answer (score 70):

From the answer of @Vicent, I already restore MySQL database as below:

Step 1. Shutdown Mysql server

Step 2. Copy database in your database folder (in linux, the default location is /var/lib/mysql). Keep same name of the database, and same name of database in mysql mode.

```
sudo cp -rf   /mnt/ubuntu_426/var/lib/mysql/database1 /var/lib/mysql/
```

Step 3:  Change own and change mode the folder:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/database1
sudo chmod -R 660 /var/lib/mysql/database1
sudo chown  mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/database1 
sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/mysql/database1
```

Step 4: Copy ibdata1 in your database folder

```
sudo cp /mnt/ubuntu_426/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 /var/lib/mysql/

sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
```

Step 5: copy  ib_logfile0 and  ib_logfile1 files in your database folder.

```
sudo cp /mnt/ubuntu_426/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 /var/lib/mysql/

sudo cp /mnt/ubuntu_426/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1 /var/lib/mysql/
```

Remember change own and change root of those files:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0

sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1
```

or

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Step 6 (Optional): My site has configuration to store files in a specific location, then I copy those to corresponding location, exactly.

Step 7: Start your Mysql server. Everything come back and enjoy it.

That is it.

See more info at: https://biolinh.wordpress.com/2017/04/01/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files-debianubuntu/

Comment: +1 for detailed step by step instructions. But I edited some statements to truly reflect what they should be.

Comment: Got a #1932 Error, unable to access data.  The databases appear, but the data is not accessible.  Running XAMPP 7.2.12 on MAC OS X Mojave.

Comment: @Steve1754a the error can from many reasons 1. Do you move a database from Mac OS to Mac OS? 2. Please check the permission of those files/ data/ table

Comment: Answers: 1. Yes; 2. I did.

I had to undertake a complete rebuild of my DB.  Could not figure out a solution.  Moral to the story: always create a backup of the DB.  I wish there were an easy way to do that automatically in XAMPP.

Comment: I oriented myself at the other file permissions from my fresh mysql install so I changed the files in the database folder to 640 (`sudo chmod -R 640 /var/lib/mysql/database1`) and the folder itself to 750 (`sudo chmod 750 /var/lib/mysql/database1`).

Comment: After doing this, I get the error: `ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file`

Comment: Hi @NickManning, Which step u get the error? can u start mýsql server? PID is only relate to process of program not db.

Comment: This worked beautifully for me but does anyone have any tips on restoring users and user privileges?

Comment: I get `Job for mysql.service failed` when I restart the server.

Comment: Actually copying (zip / unzip) the whole `var/lib/mysql` folder worked better for me. And for simplicity used:
`sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql` and `sudo chmod -R 760 /var/lib/mysql/`

Answer (score 12):

I have the same problem but was not able to successfully recover the database, based on the instructions above.

I was only able to recover mysql database folders from my Ubuntu OS. My problem is how to recover my database with those unreadable mysql data folders. So I switched back to win7 OS for development environment.

*NOTE
I have an existing database server running in win7 and I only need few database files to retrieve from the recovered files. To successfully recover the database files from Ubuntu OS I need to freshly install mysql database server (same version from Ubuntu OS in my win7 OS) to recover everything in that old database server.

1. Make another new mysql database server same version from the
   recovered files.
2. Stop the mysql server
3. copy the recovered folder and paste in the
   (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data) mysql database is
   stored.
4. copy the ibdata1 file located in linux mysql installed folder and
   paste it in (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data). Just overwrite    the existing or make backup before replacing.
5. start the mysql server and check if you have successfully recovered
   the database files.
6. To use the recovered database in my currently used mysql server
   simply export the recovered database and import it my existing mysql
   server.

Hope these will help, because nothing else worked for me.

Comment: method also works on ubuntu/debian with  ibdata1, ib_logfile0, and ib_logfile1 files and database folder. user won't be copied, but then you could add a new user to the database and dump it with that.

Answer (score 10):

If you are restoring the folder don't forget to chown the files to mysql:mysql 
`chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql-data`
 otherwise you will get errors when trying to drop a database or add new column etc..

and restart MySQL

```
service mysql restart
```

Comment: this isn't really an answer to the question but was very helpful.

Comment: actualy you should not chown everything to mysql, the mysql database folder should retain root group

Answer (score 2):

With MySql 5.1 (Win7). To recreate DBs (InnoDbs) I've replaced all contents of following dirs (my.ini params):

```
datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/"
innodb_data_home_dir="C:/MySQL Datafiles/"
```

After that I started MySql Service and all works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this trying to revive an accidentally deleted Docker Container (oraclelinux's MySQL) from a luckily-not-removed docker volume that had the DB data in physical files.

So, all I wanted to do was to turn the data from physical files into a `.sql` importable file to recreate the container with the DB and the data.

I tried [biolin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43175810), but ran into some `[InnoDB] Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID` errors, after restart.  I realized that doing open hurt surgery on certain folders/files there is quite trickey.

The solution that worked for me was temporarily changing the `datadir=` in `my.cnf` to the available folder and restarting the MySQL server.  It did the job perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is! Just add them to your database-folder ( depending on the OS ) and run a command such as "MySQL Fix Permissions". This re-stored the database. See too it that the correct permissions are set on the files aswell.

Comment: I did it, but I it does not recognizes the tables. As I said in my  comment on previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I once copied these files to the database storage folder for a mysql database which was working, started the db and waited for it to "repair" the files, then extracted them with mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply removing the tc.log in /var/lib/mysql was enough to start mariadb/mysql again.

Comment: this is not an issue of being able to start/restart mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

The icon remained orange with empty error log, until I accidentally discovered I had to replace/update names in `my.cnf` file from the old directory name `wamp64` to `wamp` in the new PC.

Answer (score 0):

From the answer of Biolinh

After doing the detailed procedures, I got the following error:

mysqlcheck: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to server during query when executing 'REPAIR TABLE ... '

Then I also copied the /var/lib/mysql/mysql directory from the backup and ran the command:

mysql_secure_installation

After that all works fine.