# Re installing Wamp Server without replacing the existing mysql database

Tags: mysql, wamp

I have some problem with WAMP server installed on my computer, every time I am trying to access a server file in the browser the page keeps on loading for hours and does not give me any errors.

So what I though is to go ahead and install and new one but my existing MySQL database has lot of data inside it that I do not want to loose, I tried to backup the database using command line but no help there as well.

Is there any way I can install a new WAMP server while keeping my existing MySQL database?

Answer (score 9):

The wamp server stores all of mysql database table in .frm formate inside `WAMP_DIR_LOCATION\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.16\data` you need to rename this `"data"` folder to `"data-old"`

And when you have reinstall the wamp server just rename the `"data-old"` folder to `"data"` In this way you will not lose your database.

Answer (score 1):

In the "WAMP_LOCATION/mysql/data" folder are the tables for MySQL. You can copy the folder and make a backup.

But you should look that you install the same version again. Sometimes MySQL has a problem with different versions.

Comment: the files there are in ".frm" format so i am not sure how to make a backup from those files :-(

Comment: Copy the complete data folder :)

Comment: thank you so much stony and i have also got some help from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files