# How to run Glassfish server with wamp?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp, mysql-workbench

I am running a NetBeans project on my Windows machine with Glassfish server with *MySQL server 5.6*. Now I installed *wamp 3.1.3 (64bit)*, but MySQL service is not starting in wamp. I know it is because MySQL is already running on `port 3306`. I have tried to change port number for MySQL of wamp in **my.ini** and **php.ini** files, but this doesn't work for me.

I have tried so many ways to solve this but didn't succeed. Kindly guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: just use a single mySQL server.

Comment: what is the error you are getting when you try to start the wamp server?

Comment: @MartinZeitler but how? Because wamp installed it automatically before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862345/re-installing-wamp-server-without-replacing-the-existing-mysql-database

Comment: @GauthamanSahadevan "The wampmysqld64 on local computer started and then stopped. Some service stop automatically if they are not in use by other service or program."

Comment: @MartinZeitler it is about MySQL database :/

Comment: you cannot have two servers running on the same port; just alike Glassfish and Apache may be conflicting; one has to be `:80` and the other `:8080`... combined with one mySQL server, which serves two databases.

Comment: @MartinZeitler yes you are right, but my question isn't about this, I have changed port :8080 for Apache server while Glassfish is listening on :80. It is about MySQL server ...

Comment: when WAMP forcibly installs a new one, create a dump of the database and uninstall the previous one... so that you can import that dump into the one new instance, which WAMP will install.

Comment: such network service questions are considered off-topic here, therefore the close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a simple solution of my problem. The sequences of the steps has given below.

1. Backup your data from `C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data` or export your database by using MySQL Workbench
2. Remove already installed MySQL Server, using MySQL community installer
3. Now restart *wampmanager.exe*
4. `import` your data into MySQL database

Cheers. It will work smoothly.