# Restoring MySQL databases from file system back up

Tags: mysql, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

I've had a hard drive crash on me and unfortunately I do not have .sql dumps available to restore my databases. Though I do have a very recent back up of my entire file system.

I've grabbed the files from `/usr/local/var/mysql/` from my back up and placed it in my fresh reinstall at the same location.

I can see all my databases when I use `show databases;` via the command line. I can also select a database using `use <database>;`. However, when I try to access any table on the database I see: `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'database.table' doesn't exist`.

Thankfully it's only happening for a few less important databases but ideally I'd like to restore them fully.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you restarted mysql daemon after overwrite?
Also check this thread:
https://superuser.com/questions/165575/import-or-restore-mysql-databases-from-var-directory

Comment: I did stop mysql before switching out the files

Comment: did you check suggestions on given URL?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your description if you've copied all your files from `/usr/local/var/mysql/`  .  You will need different sets of files depending on whether the tables in your databases were MyISAM or InnoDB storage engines.  Please check out this comment: [Restoring MySQL database from physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files#comment1145989_484773)