# Transfer MySQL from one computer to another after a crash

Tags: mysql

My local server has just blown up and gone bust. It’s refusing to boot and just hangs with a black screen. But I can access the data when making the HDD external

I have installed my new HDD into my server and installed everything i need now i need to know how to copy MySQL data from from one crashed system to the new one?

In using Ubuntu and copied the files from:

```
/var/lib/mysql/TableName
```

To the new location but I’m getting a error from phpMyAdmin saying `cannot find file "products.frm" (errno: 13)` but when I look in:

```
/var/lib/mysql/TableName
```

It’s there and I can see it?

What am I missing? I have no other backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about copying phpmyadmin or your mysql data?

If it's phpmyadmin, I'd just reinstall it.

If it's your mysql data, it's going to take a bit more work. Start here: 
[Restoring MySQL database from physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files).

Comment: +1. Not sure who downvoted you, your answer is pretty clear.

Comment: @nietonfir The answer given by Jackie Xu actually help and solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Run the command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
```

This will show you the right location of the database folders and the containing frm files.