# Restore mySQL from physical files

Tags: mysql

I have a hard disk from another PC (win8) and would like to recover the mySql database that I used to have on this computer.

I looked at [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files) on forums and did as they advised by copying "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data" folder but it didn't change a thing. I still cannot see the database I want on phpMyAdmin.

Comment: did you stop and start mysql service?

Comment: When I did restart the mySql service, php displayed: "This page is not available".
What I previously did was: rename the current data folder in "dataBkp" and pasted the data folder from my old hard disk. Should I copy only the .frm, myd and myi files?