# Backup SQL database from var/lib/mysql

Tags: mysql

I have problem with mysql and it can not start. If I delete folder

```
var/lib/mysql
```

and then I reinstall mysql it works.

If I restore old files to var/lib/mysql then it doesn't work.

- I have a database there that i need to backup.

I tried mysqldump  but I get

```
mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect
```

so is there a way to generate a .sql file from

```
var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Why it doesn't start? You should fix the problem that is preventing mysql to start.

Comment: Starting MySQL. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid).

- i try chmod 777, chown mysql:mysql  / deleting /etc/my.cnf but no sucess

Comment: Tried all of these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file Also, try restoring data folder only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files Google is also your friend: "recover mysql from files"