# MySQL restoring database functions using frm, myd and myi files

Tags: mysql, database, nginx, database-restore

MySQL had an error updating and caused my database to stop working correctly. I had to reinstall mysql during this process I was looking up how to restore my database after reinstalling. I was able to restore the database with all the tables and data inside them using the instructions in the following post:

[Restoring database from physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files)

But I noticed the functions weren't restored with the rest of the database. Anyhow I was wondering if someone could give me a hand with this?

I am running mysql on an nginx server. All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stored functions and stored procedures for all databases are stored in the `proc` table inside the `mysql` schema.

You'd need to restore the proc.FRM, proc.MYD, etc. files, inside the mysql directory, preferrably with the server stopped, since your reinstalled server already has those -- presumably empty.