# How to convert my database folder to sql

Tags: mysql

I have created project about 'local search' about 2 years ago which is incompleted. The project is in php and mysql. At that time i was installed WAMP. Then several times I changed my pc's Operating system.

Now I have to start working on this project again but I have installed XAMP. I didn't export database 'local_search_data' at that time. But i found folder 'WAMP' is there and I found database 'local_search_data' but in folder.

My question is now How I convert this 'local_search_data' folder to database(sql) format so that I can import it from mysql.

Comment: It depends on the table engine you used when you created the database. But this question is really for DBAs, since this is purely database admin stuff, nothing to do with sw development. Btw, if you have not installed a fresh MySQL server, but kept the old one around, then you do not even have to recover the database.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer was it, and what version of Windows are you now running?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the MYSQLServer from the old WAMPServer will run in your new OS you can do this.

First ensure XAMPP is stopped, and make sure its Apache and MYSQL services are stopped.

Launch `\wamp\wampmanager.exe`

Using the wampmanager menus do

```
wampmanager -> MYSQL -> Service -> Install Service
```

This should install a service called `wampmysqld` or `wampmysqld64` if you were running a 64bit WAMPServer, and the old MYSQL version will now be startable.

```
wampmanager -> MYSQL -> Service -> Start Service
```

You can now do a backup of your old database(s) using the command line tools like `mysql.exe` or `mysqldump.exe`

If you wanted to get the old WAMPServer running you could also do

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Start Service
```

And you would have your old WAMPServer up and running exactly the way it was.

#### Possible issues:

If you do not have all the necessary MSVC runtime libraries installed restarting Apache may not work. But these can easily be download and installed. See POINT 20 on [the troubleshooting guide on the WAMPServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915) There are links on that page that will help you download them all for 32 and 64bit systems.

Remember if you run 64bit Windows, you need to download the 32bit AND 64bit versions of the MSVC runtimes

***You might have to download the MSVC 2008 32bit runtime to get wampmanager to run.***

Comment: but i dont have wamp installed

Comment: You said you found the old WAMP folder! Thats all you need assuming it contains everything it originally contained

Comment: WAMPServer only _Installs_ the 2 services, `wampapache` and `wampmysqld` Everything else is just contained in the `\wamp` folder. When you upgraded or re-installed your OS those 2 services is all that got lost, and is easily reinstalled by above 2 commands

Answer (score 0):

Here, I just found some part of solution. I just started XAMPP and copy 'local_search_data' folder into xampp\mysql\data folder. Then I got table structures. I know it showing problem of engin. But now I got at least table sstructures. Thank You.