# Recovering MySQL database in WAMP server

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I have uninstalled the WAMP server on my local PC, but before that I have copied the files in the WAMP directory. Now, I have reinstalled the WAMP. Is there any way to get the previous database back?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files refers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restoring MySQL database from physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files)

Comment: Did you reinstall the same version of WAMPServer and therefore the same version of MySQL