# Transfer a MySQL database from one AMPPS installation to a newer one

Tags: mysql, macos, macos-catalina, ampps

I've just upgraded macos to Catalina and the version I had of AMPPS stopped working.

I've installed the newest one available, however the mysql database came empty (of course).

How can I move all tables and databases from the older AMPPS installation to the newer one? Runing the previous AMPPS installation in order to export as SQL isn't an option because Catalina won't run it :-(

In the old installation all tables are stored as `.frm` and `.ibd` files. I tried copying the `var` folder to the new AMPPS installation and it didn't work. Tried to merge the contents of the old `var` folder with the new one and it didn't work either.

Comment: Do a backup on one server with phpmyadmin and restore again on the other server. Workbench can transfer databases directly if he is connected to both.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but i can't run the previous mysql server because the previous ampps version does not work on macos catalina

Comment: then make this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the newer version of AMPPS came with MySQL 8, which is incompatible with MySQL 5.4, from the previous AMPPS version. I ended up losing the data from the previous database, which was not such a great problem because it was just test data from several apps in development.

Perhaps if I installed MySQL 5.4 on macos Catalina without AMPPS I would be able to copy the files from the previous AMPPS version and then export it to MySQL 8, but haven't really tried it.