# MySQL Server crash XAMPP

Tags: mysql

I have a XAMPP MySQL Server and it worked perfectly until today. I started my Computer and started the MySQL Server via the XAMPP Control Panel. It says first that its started but then this:

```
11:37:26  [main]    Initialisere Control Panel
11:37:26  [main]    Windows Version:  Enterprise  64-bit
11:37:26  [main]    XAMPP Version: 7.3.11
11:37:26  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.2.4  [ Compiled: Jun 5th 2019 ]
11:37:26  [main]    Dein Benutzerprofil besitzt keine Administratorenrechte! Das reicht aus für die meisten
11:37:26  [main]    Anwendungsfunktionen, aber wann immer du etwas mit Windows-Diensten tun möchtest,
11:37:26  [main]    wird eine Sicherheitsabfrage erscheinen oder etwas wird garnicht erst funktionieren!
11:37:26  [main]    Also denke daran diese Anwendung mit Administratorrechten zu starten!
11:37:26  [main]    XAMPP Installationsverzeichnis: "c:\xampp\"
11:37:26  [main]    Voraussetzungen werden geprüft
11:37:27  [main]    Alle Voraussetzungen sind erfüllt
11:37:27  [main]    Initialisiere Module
11:37:27  [main]    Starte Check-Timer
11:37:27  [main]    Control Panel bereit
11:37:28  [mysql]   Versuche MySQL Windows Dienst zu starten...
11:37:34  [mysql]   Statusänderung erkannt: gestartet
11:37:41  [mysql]   Statusänderung erkannt: gestoppt
11:37:41  [mysql]   Fehler: MySQL wurde unerwartet beendet
11:37:41  [mysql]   Ursache könnte ein geblockter Port, fehlende Abhängigkeiten,
11:37:41  [mysql]   fehlende Berechtigungen, ein Absturz oder ein Abbruch einer anderen Methode sein.
11:37:41  [mysql]   Drücke den Logs Button um error logs zu sehen und prüfe
11:37:41  [mysql]   im Windows Event Viewer für weitere Hinweise
11:37:41  [mysql]   Wenn du weitere Hilfe benötigst, kopiere den kompletten Inhalt des Log Fensters
11:37:41  [mysql]   und füge ihn als Ergänzung in einem neuen Forum Eintrag hinzu.
```

[Here is the Error Log](https://controlc.com/7b75ba8f)

Maybe some of you know whats the Problem. Im not a Database guy so I dont know why it cannot start. MySQL Port should not be blocked and I never changed something since last time it worked.

Thanks in advance

Lukas

Comment: have you installed pruor another myasl madriadb server on your machine? check services(Dienste) and eventviewer (ereignisanzeige)

Comment: never installed something different. I only installed XAMPP. The Problem is that I dont get the database up and running and I dont have a Save of the DB so its essential for me to get it back up...

Comment: And under Services I only find mysql nothing with myasl or madriadb (maybe u ment MariaDB but thats not the case either...)

Comment: Restart your computer the log shows that ,mysql started.every time

Comment: Services shows that mysql isnt running and I already tried to restart... :/

Comment: see what happens when you start mysql from services.you also dodn't tell if event viwer showed some error messages too

Comment: The Only thing what is in Event Viewer is

mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

If I start it in the Services Window it says:

The Service "mysql" on "local computer" couldn´t be started
Error 1067: The Process aborted unexpected

Comment: yepp that is a good cause to crash The mysql.db table contains information about database-level privileges.  try mysqlcheck -A --auto-repair and i would check the s.m.a.r.t information of your harddrive

Comment: mysqlcheck doesnt work because the DB isnt running

Comment: the last think i can think of install a new server and restore the data from  the files see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files