# How to get mysql to disk

Tags: mysql, database

**Without stopping mysql** I am trying to copy it to disk and copy that directory over to a new server to use. Apparently `FLUSH` and `mysqldump` don't work, since `mysqldump` points to a new file, and `FLUSH` only updates the `logfile` files.

Is there any way to dump what is in the mysql database to the filesystem?

From [Restoring MySQL database from physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files):

> You should be able to restore by copying them in your database folder (In linux, the default location is /var/lib/mysql/)

If the server *is* running the database is stored in memory. It feels *deficient* if mysql is **inable** to flush the memory to disk. Please let me know if this is possible ***while the mysql server is running***.

EDIT: Any type of snapshot, AWS, DigitalOcean, Azure, is worthless without this figured out.

Comment: _"If the server is running the database is stored in memory"_ No it's not. Maybe parts of it, or maybe if you have a very small database. But imagine a multi TB database; how do you suppose that is all stored in memory? Besides; MySQL could, potentially, be writing to disk continually. What are you trying to accomplish? Because what you're doing now is begging for corrupt a corrupt (copy of) your database. _"Any type of snapshot, AWS, DigitalOcean, Azure, is worthless without this figured out."_ That's NOT how snapshots work.

Comment: "mysqldump points to a new file"...why is that a problem, if you just want to copy it to another server?

Comment: Maybe you should look into replication? HA cluster?