# Get databases mysql dump from a external disk. Is it possible?

Tags: mysql

I've connected an esternal disk 'D' via usb, with all my mysql databases, to my pc 'C'. For both there's windows 10 with WAMP. Is it possible to get a dump of all databases from 'D' ? The path to the application is d://xampp/phpmyadmin

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear! Do you have two mysql in two different path? What does mean "to my pc 'C'"?

Comment: I've this hdu from a notebook broken and i've connected it via usb (it becames phisically disk 'D'). Now i need to backup the mysql databases stored into it. Is it possibile?

Comment: Yes, you can. Read this : [Restoring MySQL database from physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files)