# Recover the database on an external hard drive

Tags: database-restore

I have projects on an internal hard drive
After I changed the hard drive. I did not export the databases. How I can recover them?.

thanks in advance

Comment: "How I can recover them?" -- Probably not at all unless you have a backup.

Comment: 1) this question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO is there to offer help in database admin questions like this one. 2) mysql and sqlite are two different database products that need to be restored differently. 3) No clue what php and phpmyadmin has to do with this question. 4) If you do not have the data, you cannot recover any data.

Answer (score -1):

You will need access to your data in the old Hard Drive.

Just check this answer: [Restoring MySQL database from physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files)

Greetings