# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, pam-unix

Ok so all of a sudden sql is not working properly on my server. When i run `sudo service mysql start` it says:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When i run `systemctl status mysql.service` it shows:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: activating (start) since Wed 2021-04-14 03:08:17 UTC; 4s ago
Process: 12884 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 12892 (mysqld)
Status: "Server startup in progress"
Tasks: 2 (limit: 1136)
Memory: 2.7M
CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
         └─12892 [mysqld]
```

When i run `journalctl -xe` is shows:

```
Apr 14 03:04:43 otzivio-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-fra1-01 sudo[11492]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): 
authentication failure; logname=ashok uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=ashok rhost=  user=ashok
Apr 14 03:04:47 otzivio-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-fra1-01 sudo[11492]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): 
conversation failed
Apr 14 03:04:47 otzivio-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-fra1-01 sudo[11492]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could 
not identify password for [ashok]
Apr 14 03:05:20 otzivio-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-intel-fra1-01 sudo[11748]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): 
authentication failure; logname=ashok uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=ashok rhost=  user=ashok
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Sorry its mysql

Answer (score 1):

First run " sudo apt-get install -f" for resolve dependences, if it doesn't works, review your config files, permission, etc. Try to see if thare is any update  that happened.

In the last case, when nothing works. Try to reinstall by "sudo apt-get autoremove mysql-server && apt-get install mysql-server" but make sure you have all backups os config files and sql...

I don't know if it will really help, but in my job we receve some updates in the server from night to the day that pull all down kkk. After some bad experiences i create the backup of the backp of the backup daily...

Comment: I am not able to view the tables either as `mysql -u root -p` is also not working atm. So how do i backup my databases?

Comment: follow this steps, it will teach you how to find .db files on your server [link](https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7019203) after this, you need to do this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files)