# mysql workbench dropped table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

my MySQL workbench setup with a database on it. I was using xampp with it but xampp stopped working so I uninstalled and reinstalled it. could this be the issue as to why the table went missing?

Answer (score 0):

workbench is only a Gui, it will not drop anything without any user input.

MySQL server and xammp would work parallel when you choose a different port for one of them.

Your problem is that both save theier files in diffrent path(default)

MYSQL saves its data in

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data
```

While xammp stores their database in

```
C:/xampp/mysql/data
```

in [Restoring MySQL database from physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files) you find a tutprial how to restore your tables from the files from  your old installation