# How can I read data directly from frm, myd, myi files?

Tags: mysql

An old Windows XP computer HD crashed and the user managed to copy the FRM, MYD, MYI files onto a pen drive.

I have installed the latest mySQL onto my computer.

How can I attach or read the data from these files please?

Thanks
JP

Comment: I think [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16875/restore-table-from-frm-and-ibd-file) might help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restoring MySQL database from physical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files)