# Can I recover data from MySQL Ubuntu 8.0 to Windows?

Tags: mysql, cross-platform

This question was originally asked on Ask Ubuntu... maybe better luck here.
From a dead 16.04 Ubuntu system I have access to the disk so I'm trying to recover the data from the MySQL data folder in `/opt/bitnami/mysql/`.  Yes, it was a Bitnami LAMP stack 7.3.15-0.

Is it possible read or use that data on a Win64 MySQL install?   Assuming it's possible to do, which version should I install on Windows to match the 8.0.18 source system? A higher version could recognize data produced by the older one?

Comment: If you know the MySQL version from the old installation it is possible. Best chances are to attempt this in WSL to get the database running once again and do a full dump.

Comment: You can read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484750/restoring-mysql-database-from-physical-files for some idea.